# Как изменить get запрос через htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

У меня есть страница:

```
site.ru?wt_region_by_default_=Санкт-Петербург
```

Хочу, чтобы было:

```
site.ru/city/sankt-peterburg
```

Города могут быть разными.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вот что я пишу для умных URL. Думаю Вам подойдет, только под себя указать

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ /?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/$ /?controller=$1&action=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ /?controller=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ /?controller=$1&{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
```

Больше всего Вам подойдет особенно первая строка
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)
Так как последняя например это для ссылок типа :
site/product/1